# How do I present a configuration screen for an Atlassian plugin?

Tags: plugins, configuration, bitbucket-server

I'm building a plugin to send http requests to a server whenever I open or edit a pull request in atlassian stash. I've gotten the plugin to work with hardcoded values (like the url, various url parameters, etc.) but now I need to present a configuration screen so these values can be set after installing the plugin. All I need to configure is a couple text strings and a key-value mapping of strings to strings. Nothing complicated!

Unfortunately the stash and atlassian api is a little fuzzy: there's information for linking to a servlet, or something, and describing how once you have the configuration object to connect to it, but that's all I can find. They also point at a couple examples like google maps and webdav plugins, but without any comments it might as well be latin.

Can someone point me to an example or tutorial that shows how to present a configuration panel for a stash (or atlassian) plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Atlassian plugin framework is quite a broad topic, particularly because there are subtle differences in capabilities between the various concrete products (JIRA, Confluence, FishEye, Stash, etc.) and as such, there are resources all over the net for helping understand, interact with and program against the available framework components and API endpoints.  I'm working through the process of adding configuration myself and have found the following resources very helpful (although they may be generic to the Atlassian plugin framework, most of the concepts still apply):

https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Creating+an+Admin+Configuration+Form

https://developer.atlassian.com/stash/docs/latest/reference/plugin-module-types/plugin-modules.html